# Getting a certain character closest from cursor in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, cursor, textarea

So here is what i am trying to achieve.
I have a text area. In it I can write something like:

```
"This is <html> and this is <java>"
```

What i am doing is trigger a suggestion list when a '<' is inserted. My problem is how do i get the value from the '<' until the cursor so that i can replace it if a suggestion is picked from the list. So say I start writing

```
"This is <ht"
```

How do i get the 'ht' here if my cursor is right after it? I should be able to get achieve this even on the nth tag. So for

```
"This is <html> and <java> plus <ph"
```

I should get me "ph"

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/VBKBR/) what I came up with. It's obviously faulty, and I didn't think it was worthy of its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [caret plugin](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php)? It has a function that allows you to replace the highlighted text.

Comment: that looks like it has all the components needed. I'm working on it right now.